# php use array as array_map first argument

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

I can't kind of make out the first return statement, can anybody help to explain how it works?
the `array_map` accept a function for the first arg, but here is an array. and how does `array(&$this, '_trimData')` work? thanks for explaining.

```
private function _trimData($mParam)
{       
    if (is_array($mParam))
    {
        return array_map(array(&$this, '_trimData'), $mParam);
    }

    $mParam = trim($mParam);

    return $mParam;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a recursive function.  `_trimData` calls itself if the parameter passed to it was an array.

`array(&$this, '_trimData')` is a [callback](http://php.net/manual/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) to the current object's method `_trimData`.

The entire method could really be replaced with:

```
private function _trimData($mParam)
{ 
    array_walk_recursive($mParam, 'trim');
    return $mParam;
}
```

Comment: Got it,,,your function is much easier to understand. thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It is callback: `$this->_trimData()` (`_trimData` of object `$this`)

Answer (score 0):

A bit further of an explanation about how `array(&$this, '_trimData')` acts as a callback, despite looking like an array:

> A PHP function is passed by its name as a string... A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1. [PHP: Callbacks/Callables](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)

So in this case, the object is `&$this` and the method is `_trimData`, and making it into an array is one way PHP allows you to pass it as a callback into `array_map`.